# Using a VBA variable in SELECT Sql statement

Tags: sql, vba

Is their a way to use a declared VBA variable in a SELECT Sql statement as follows (I have a table called `myTable` and i want to set the referenced field by passing the declared string `myVar`) :
e.g passVar("English")

NB: Am using Microsoft Access

```
Private Function passVar(myVar as string)

Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim stmnt As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("SelectSubjectQuery")

stmnt = "SELECT [myTable].[myVar] = " &Chr$(34) & myVar & Chr$(34) & _

         //other SQL statements go here

qdf.SQL = stmnt

End Function
```

Each time i run the query a dialog box appears asking for the value of `mytable.myvar` instead of passing `myvar` i.e Eglish as the referenced field on `myTable`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, build the SQL statement as a string like this:

```
stmnt = "SELECT " & [myTable] & "." & [myVar] & " = " &Chr$(34) & myVar & Chr$(34) & _
```

VBA should then fill in the names for MyTable and MyVar when the code is run and the string is built.

Comment: yes I have done it as above but a dialog box appears asking me to enter the parameter value for mytable.English   ;please help

Answer (score 2):

```
stmnt = "SELECT [myTable]." & myVar & _
```

Got it to working by writing as above (no need for the equals sign as the string is passed through the function). Thanks for the insight @rcfmonarch